# How would I go about solving $11^{112114} \equiv x\pmod {113}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, coprime

I'm studying for an exam, and this is one of the practice questions:

> For what number $x \in \{0, 1, 2, ... 112\}$ is the following statement true:
>
> $$11^{112114} \equiv x  \pmod{113} $$

I have no idea how I would start this. This question is a subproblem of another involving Fermat's Little Theorem, so I'm assuming I'll have to use that, but I have no idea how.
I appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Start by observing that $112114 \equiv 2 \pmod{112}$.

Comment: Take a deep breath and count to ten. No wait, don't count that high, the solution is less. See the previous comment.